# Is there a way to use the cursor to scroll through a map indefinitely using Gosu

Tags: ruby, scroll, graphics, libgosu

I'm using Gosu (with Ruby version 2.5.5) to create my first game. I created a map and I want to implement scrolling with the cursor. Using Gosu example ["Cptn Ruby](https://github.com/gosu/gosu-examples/blob/master/examples/cptn_ruby.rb)" as a guide, I was successful to a point.

Here is what I have so far.

```
def update 
    # map.width is the number of background tiles in each row and map.height is the number of tiles in 
    # each column. Each tile is 14x14 pixels. 

    @camera_x = [[self.mouse_x - (WIDTH / 2), 0].max, @map.width * 14 - WIDTH].min
    @camera_y = [[self.mouse_y - (HEIGHT / 2), 0].max, @map.height * 14 - HEIGHT].min

end 

def draw

    @cursor.draw(self.mouse_x, self.mouse_y, 100, scale_x = 0.65, scale_y = 0.65)
    Gosu.translate(-@camera_x, -@camera_y) {@map.draw}

end
```

This does scroll, but only to maximum point. Once the cursor reaches the bottom of the screen, the camera_y value will not get greater than 239 (and the same problem goes for camera_x). I can increase the scrolling distance by multiplying the value by 2 like so:

```
@camera_y = [[(self.mouse_y - (HEIGHT / 2) * 2, 0].max, @map.height * 14 - HEIGHT].min
```

However, while I scroll further with this approach, it still stops. I would like to continuously scroll while the mouse is at the bottom (or side) of the screen. I am confused as to why it is not doing this already since gosu::update runs 60 times per second. I would have thought that every time it runs it would add to my @camera_y and/or @camera_x variables if the cursor is in the right spot, but that is not happening.

I've also tried this:

```
if self.mouse_y > (HEIGHT * 0.67)  # if mouse is in lower 3rd of screen
    @camera_y += 10
end
```

This simply moves scrolls 10 pixels once instead of continuously.

I could do this easily with a loop, but I found that loops in Gosu update or draw cause the program to crash.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to do it.

```
def initialize

        super WIDTH, HEIGHT, :fullscreen => false

        self.caption = "Ecosystem Beta"
        @map = Map.new("c:/users/12035/.atom/Ecosystem/eco_map.txt", :tileable => true)
        @cursor = Gosu::Image.new("c:/users/12035/.atom/media/cursor.png")

        @camera_x = 0
        @camera_y = 0

    end

   def update 

       if self.mouse_y > (HEIGHT * 0.67) # if mouse is in lower 3rd of screen
          @camera_y = [@camera_y += 10, 740].min # scrolls to a max of 740 pixels 

       elsif self.mouse_y < (HEIGHT * 0.33)
           @camera_y = [@camera_y -= 10, 0].max # will not scroll past the begginining of the map
       end    
   end
```